# Update JSON dictionary output

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a JSON output file following a unique structure. Some of the hierarchy's in the JSON are similar and others are slightly different.

I've tried revising the way the code is iterating to get the desired format.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from json import dump

root_dir=os.getcwd()
data_dir=os.path.join(root_dir,'Data')

filename='RowMapping.json'
volumes = list(range(1, 12))
durations= [6, 12, 24, 96]
qmap=[{'q1':[0, 13], 'q2':[16, 29], 'q3':[32, 45], 'q4':[48, 61]}, {'q1':[0, 25], 'q2':[28, 53], 'q3':[56, 81], 'q4':[84, 109]},{'q1':[0, 49], 'q2':[52, 101], 'q3':[104, 153], 'q4':[156, 205]}, {'q1':[0, 97], 'q2':[100, 197], 'q3':[200, 297], 'q4':[300, 397]}]
list_dictionary = []
mr={}
final_dictionary={}

region_sa = list(range(1, 3))  #vol 1    
region_or = list(range(1, 2))  #vol 2
region_pr = list(range(1, 2))  #vol 3
region_hi = list(range(1, 2))  #vol 4
region_pi = list(range(1, 2))  #vol 5
region_ca = list(range(1, 15)) #vol 6
region_ak = list(range(1, 3))  #vol 7
region_mw = list(range(1, 5))  #vol 8
region_se = list(range(1, 3))  #vol 9
region_ne = list(range(1, 3))  #vol 10
region_tx = list(range(1, 4))  #vol 11

region_overall = [region_sa, region_or, region_pr, region_hi, region_pi, region_ca, region_ak, region_mw, region_se, region_ne, region_tx]

for i, val in enumerate(durations):
    mr[val]={'map':qmap[i]}

for region in region_overall:
    dictionary = {}
    for i in region:
        dictionary[i] = {'durations':mr}
    list_dictionary.append(dictionary.copy())

for i, val in enumerate(volumes):
    final_dictionary[int(val)]={'regions':list_dictionary[i]}

with open(os.path.join(data_dir,filename), 'w') as f:
     dump(final_dictionary, f)
```

Current outputted dictionary:

```
{1: {'regions': {1: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   2: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}}}},
 2: {'regions': {1: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}}}},
 3: {'regions': {1: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}}}},
 4: {'regions': {1: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}}}},
 5: {'regions': {1: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}}}},
 6: {'regions': {1: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   2: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   3: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   4: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   5: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   6: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   7: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   8: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   9: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   10: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   11: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   12: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   13: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   14: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}}}},
 7: {'regions': {1: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   2: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}}}},
 8: {'regions': {1: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   2: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   3: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   4: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}}}},
 9: {'regions': {1: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   2: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}}}},
 10: {'regions': {1: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   2: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}}}},
 11: {'regions': {1: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   2: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}},
   3: {'durations': {6: {'map': {'q1': [0, 13],
       'q2': [16, 29],
       'q3': [32, 45],
       'q4': [48, 61]}},
     12: {'map': {'q1': [0, 25],
       'q2': [28, 53],
       'q3': [56, 81],
       'q4': [84, 109]}},
     24: {'map': {'q1': [0, 49],
       'q2': [52, 101],
       'q3': [104, 153],
       'q4': [156, 205]}},
     96: {'map': {'q1': [0, 97],
       'q2': [100, 197],
       'q3': [200, 297],
       'q4': [300, 397]}}}}}}}
```

For the first 3 volumes (1, 2, and 3 out of 11 total volumes), I want to update the 'q1', 'q2', 'q3' and 'q4' lists to be "q1":[0, 9], "q2":[11, 20], "q3":[22, 31], "q4":[33, 42].

For all the volumes, I want to add a 'skiprows' element at the "map" level of the JSON. For the first 3 volumes, the 'skiprows' would have a value of 12 while the rest of the volumes would have a 'skiprows' value of 8. I've attempted to this by adding/revising these lines of code:

```
skiprows = [12]*3 + [8]*8



for vol in range(len(volumes)):
    for i, val in enumerate(durations):
        mr[val]={'map':qmap[i], 'skiprows':skiprows[i]}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your attempt?

Comment: I get 'skiprows' to be 12, 12, 12, and 8 at all of the map levels of each duration for each volume. The 'skiprows' pattern should be 12, 12, 12, and 12 for the first 3 volumes and then 8, 8, 8, 8 for the rest of the volumes. Also, the 'q1', 'q2', 'q3' and 'q4' values for the first three volumes should be different based on what I described above. I'm thinking maybe using a for loop and if statement to revise the information needed for the first three volumes could do the trick but I'm just now sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Maybe this link can help to visualize the JSON output format after running the code http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: Thanks, but `pprint(final_dictionary)` provides a better visualization, in my opinion. I think you should [edit] your question and show what you want the updated JSON dictionary to look like with respect to that.

Comment: I figured it out @martineau. See the answer I posted. It was working with additional for loops, if statements, and adding new variables.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

These lines of code work:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from json import dump

root_dir=os.getcwd()
data_dir=os.path.join(root_dir,'Data')


filename='RowMapping.json'
volumes = list(range(1, 12))
durations = [6, 12, 24, 96]
qmapA=[{'q1':[0, 13], 'q2':[16, 29], 'q3':[32, 45], 'q4':[48, 61]}, {'q1':[0, 25], 'q2':[28, 53], 'q3':[56, 81], 'q4':[84, 109]},{'q1':[0, 49], 'q2':[52, 101], 'q3':[104, 153], 'q4':[156, 205]}, {'q1':[0, 97], 'q2':[100, 197], 'q3':[200, 297], 'q4':[300, 397]}]
qmapB=[{'q1':[0, 9], 'q2':[11, 20], 'q3':[22, 31], 'q4':[33, 42]}]*4
list_dictionary1_3 = []
list_dictionary4_11 = []
mr1_3={}
mr4_11={}
final_dictionary={}
skiprows1_3 = [12]*4
skiprows4_11 = [8]*4

region_sa = list(range(1, 3))  #vol 1    
region_or = list(range(1, 2))  #vol 2
region_pr = list(range(1, 2))  #vol 3
region_hi = list(range(1, 2))  #vol 4
region_pi = list(range(1, 2))  #vol 5
region_ca = list(range(1, 15)) #vol 6
region_ak = list(range(1, 3))  #vol 7
region_mw = list(range(1, 5))  #vol 8
region_se = list(range(1, 3))  #vol 9
region_ne = list(range(1, 3))  #vol 10
region_tx = list(range(1, 4))  #vol 11

region_overall = [region_sa, region_or, region_pr, region_hi, region_pi, region_ca, region_ak, region_mw, region_se, region_ne, region_tx]

for vol in volumes:
    if vol <= 3:
        for i, val in enumerate(durations):
            mr1_3[val]={'map':qmapB[i], 'skiprows':skiprows1_3[i]}
    else:
        for i, val in enumerate(durations):
            mr4_11[val]={'map':qmapA[i], 'skiprows':skiprows4_11[i]}  

for vol in volumes:
    if vol <= 3:    
        for region in region_overall:
            dictionary = {}
            for i in region:
                dictionary[i] = {'durations':mr1_3}
            list_dictionary1_3.append(dictionary.copy())
    else:
        for region in region_overall:
            dictionary = {}
            for i in region:
                dictionary[i] = {'durations':mr4_11}
            list_dictionary4_11.append(dictionary.copy())

for i, val in enumerate(volumes):
    if val <= 3:
        final_dictionary[int(val)]={'regions':list_dictionary1_3[i]}
    else:
        final_dictionary[int(val)]={'regions':list_dictionary4_11[i]}

with open(os.path.join(data_dir,filename), 'w') as f:
     dump(final_dictionary, f)
```

The results can be seen here by copying and pasting the above output:

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/